# Spring boot and angular Test get error 406

Tags: angular, unit-testing, spring-boot, karma-jasmine

Hell.I am doing units test with Jasmine,Karma and in angular. When i executed the next test, i get this exception:

feign.FeignException: status 406 reading AppRbp#getReports(DTOReport)

The code:
The method i am testing

```
  exportReportSwitch() {
switch (this.modulo) {
  case 'RBP':
    this.serviceRbp.getReports(this.reportSelected).subscribe(response => this.savePdf(response, this.reportSelected));
    break;
  case 'CCR':
    this.serviceCcr.getReports(this.reportSelected).subscribe(response => this.savePdf(response, this.reportSelected));
  break;
  case 'Micro':
    this.serviceMicro.getReports(this.reportSelected).subscribe(response => this.savePdf(response, this.reportSelected));
  break;
  default:
  break;
}
```

The test

```
it('Test unitario metodo exportReportSwitch() en caso de que Sea Micro', () => {
//Arrange
const serviceMicro = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MicroService);
const serviceSpy = spyOn(serviceMicro, 'getReports').and.callThrough();
when(serviceMicro.getReports('Listado 1').subscribe()).thenReturn();
component.modulo = 'Micro';
//Act
component.exportReportSwitch();
//Assert
expect(serviceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  });
```

The backend method

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/getReports", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getReports(@RequestBody DTOReports dto) {
    String nameFile = dto.getReport();
    String jrxmlDir = "src/main/resources/jrxml/";
    String jasperDir = jrxmlDir + "/jasper/";
    byte[] outputPDF=null;
    try {
        File mainfile = ResourceUtils.getFile(jrxmlDir +nameFile + ".jrxml");
        compilerToJasper(jrxmlDir, jasperDir, nameFile);

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", jasperDir);
        JasperReport report=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(mainfile.getAbsolutePath());
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,parameters,this.dataSource.getConnection());

        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfReportStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(pdfReportStream));
        exporter.exportReport();

        outputPDF = pdfReportStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Se ha producido la siguiente excepcion: " + e);
    }

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));
    responseHeaders.setContentLength(outputPDF.length);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(outputPDF, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Angular service

```
    getReports(file: String): Observable<any> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({
        'report': file
    });
    return this.llamarServicioDownloadFile(this.baseURL_RBP + GET_REPORTS_RBP, body);
}
```

and finally the error in a image

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRyxp.png;)
If you need more information, please dont dude to ask me. I am noob in StackOverflow
Sorry for my english, i am spanish

Comment: First, when using unit tests you do not test across layers, you are testing the component in isolation. The only use the backend is, is for the url you expect to use and the data you expect it to return. Your service that you inject into your angular component is an angular service that communicates with the Spring backend you have. Can you post your angular service code.

Comment: Yes, i added the angular service. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. I needed Smock the service.

```
 const serviceSpy = spyOn(serviceMicro, 'getReports').and.returnValue(Observable.of());
```

instead of:

```
     const serviceSpy = spyOn(serviceMicro, 'getReports').and.callThrough();;
```